# Bundle corresponding XML entries

Tags: xml, sed, xml-parsing, grep, tr

I have a sample xml file `input.xml`:

```
<employee>
<userid>1</userid>
<name>Puneetha B M</name>
<designation>Developer</designation>
</employee>
<employee>
<userid>2</userid>
<name>Bhoomika</name>
<designation>Analyst</designation>
</employee>
```

Now I need to transform it into the following format (output file name `output.xmlb`): I need to bring each record to one line

```
<employee> <userid>1</userid> <name>Puneetha B M</name> <designation>Developer</designation> </employee>
<employee> <userid>2</userid> <name>Bhoomika</name> <designation>Analyst</designation> </employee>
```

For this transformation the author have used the following command in unix.

```
cat input.xml | tr -d '&' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\r' ' ' | sed 's|</employee>|</employee>\n|g' | grep -v '^\s*$' > output.xmlb
```

Anyone please help me to understand that how these unix commands are working .
If you don't understand my question well the plz visit the link: **http://blog.puneethabm.in/load-xml-file-to-hive-without-java-code/**
here I am trying to understand the Step1

Comment: [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat+input.xml+%7C+tr+-d+%27%26%27+%7C+tr+%27%5Cn%27+%27+%27+%7C+tr+%27%5Cr%27+%27+%27+%7C+sed+%27s%7C%3C%2Femployee%3E%7C%3C%2Femployee%3E%5Cn%7Cg%27+%7C+grep+-v+%27%5E%5Cs*%24%27+%3E+output.xmlb) gives you a start. If you need to know more about what any specific command is doing you can read its man page for more details (part of that information is given at the previous link). Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Thank u. The website is superb. I am trying understand how data is flowing through the each command one by one.

Answer (score 0):

gawk Test OK

```
awk -F'<' '!a{a=$2;next}{if($0~a){print FS a,b,$0;a=b=""}else{b=b?b" "$0:$0}}' file
<employee> <userid>1</userid> <name>Puneetha B M</name> <designation>Developer</designation> </employee>
<employee> <userid>2</userid> <name>Bhoomika</name> <designation>Analyst</designation> </employee>
```

OR Use Sed

```
sed '/employee/{:a;N;/<\/employee>/!ba;s/\n/ /g;}' file
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question of "how is this working".

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
tr '\n' ' ' <infile | sed 's|\(</employee>\) |\1\n|g' >outfile
```

- `tr` replaces all newlines with spaces.
- `sed` adds a newline after a closing employee tag.

---

The output:

```
<employee> <userid>1</userid> <name>Puneetha B M</name> <designation>Developer</designation> </employee>
<employee> <userid>2</userid> <name>Bhoomika</name> <designation>Analyst</designation> </employee>
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question of "how is this working".

Comment: Could you plz explain me how  the following portion is of command is working:
    sed 's|</employee>|</employee>\n|g' | grep -v '^\s*$'